# Golang, exec and back ticks shell command

Tags: go

I am trying to use os.exec (https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/12/29/shelled-out-commands-in-golang/) with a command like:

```
value=`something`; echo $value
```

But it appears to the back ticks are messing with the command of the strings.Split I do.

If I use

```
something
```

it works

How can I use the back ticks? Do I have to find out another way to write my command?

Thanks

Comment: I find out I could do $() instead of `` but hum...Actually my command is more complex than just that:
```nginx=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep nginx | wc -l); dash=$(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep Dash | wc -l); if [ $nginx -gt 0 -a $dash -gt 0 ]; then echo OK; else echo Error; fi```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go executes these commands a way that you can't use shell things, because it creates a new process.
So you should create a new shell process, for example:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "value=`ls`; echo $value")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

Let me know if it's not what you want!